# Wordpress Ajax post not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have the following ajax post being made in my wordpress plugin:

```
            jQuery.ajax({

                type:"post",
                dataType:"json",
                url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
                data: {action: 'submit_data', data: info},
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.type == "success") {

                        alert("Success");
                    }
                    else  {

                        alert("Fail");
                    }
                }
            });
```

This is where I register the submit_data action in my plugin file:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_submit_data", "submit_data");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_data", "submit_data");

function submit_data() {

    echo "<script> alert('hello'); </script";
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
    die();
}
```

For some reason the ajax request fails, but I cant see from my code here why?

Comment: What do you mean by _fails_?

Comment: By fail I mean it does not send, I do not receive a 'success' or a 'fail' or a 'hello' alert

Comment: How are you send ajax request? What events you have bind it to? Also see the developer console for the errors.

Comment: Checked the console, no errors. The ajax post is in a javascript file that handles the clicking of a button. I set up an alert just before the ajax post to ensure the data is being captured correctly and it is.

Answer (score -1):

Just add .fail method in jQuery ajax function.

---

`var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });`

Regards,
HBK